# Auto updating Wordpress loop

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, loops, websocket

I've been doing Research on this subject and have hit a brick wall. The site i'm creating requires a way to automatically pull posts into a loop as soon as they are published without the page being refreshed, sort of like a live feed of Wordpress posts on the "home" page.

Is this possible? I've been looking into web sockets and have had no luck trying to integrate them into Wordpress.

I don't want to create a polling loop as this will be load heavy, if i could find a way to add new data to the loop as and when that would be fantastic.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would gratefully appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: i think a pulling loop of jquery is the only nearest solution I can think of.

Comment: There are a few other people wanting the same thing and there does not seem to be a decent solution. check here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32377/automatically-pull-newer-posts-and-append-to-current-page and here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107222/auto-refresh-post-list-after-x-seconds